# Remove View after animation

Tags: android

I have a view that does an animation and then should be removed or at least sent to the back so i can reuse it. I'm having trouble attaching a listener to it.

I've been stuck on this for about 2 weeks so any help at all is really appreciated.

I'm just trying to get the card to fling off the screen, disappear and then be deleted.

```
package com.example.trevorwood.biggles.study;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.trevorwood.biggles.R;


public class StudyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout mFlipCardLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout mCardFlippedButtons;
    FrameLayout mCardFrame;
    View mCurrentAnimCardContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_study);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.study_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);//0xAARRGGBB
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mFlipCardLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flip_card_linear_layout);
        mCardFlippedButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_flipped_buttons);
        mCardFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_frame);

        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

        makeNewCard();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/HomeFragment button
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void onCardClick(View view) {
        flipCard();
    }

    public void onCardFlippedButtonsClick(View view) {
        Integer numberPressed;
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.color_button_1:numberPressed = 1;break;
            case R.id.color_button_2:numberPressed = 2;break;
            case R.id.color_button_3:numberPressed = 3;break;
            case R.id.color_button_4:numberPressed = 4;break;
            case R.id.color_button_5:numberPressed = 5;break;
            default:numberPressed = 0;
        }

        saveCardStats(numberPressed);
        flingCardAway();
        resetForNewCard();
        makeNewCard();
    }

    private void flipCard() {
        FrameLayout cardFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_frame);
        Integer childCount = cardFrame.getChildCount();
        Log.d("Simple","childCount: "+childCount);

        View cardContainer = findViewById(R.id.card_container);
        View cardFace = findViewById(R.id.card_front);
        View cardBack = findViewById(R.id.card_back);

        FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);

        if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mFlipCardLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCardFlippedButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            flipAnimation.reverse();
        }else{
            mFlipCardLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCardFlippedButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        cardContainer.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
    }

    private void saveCardStats(Integer numberPressed){

    }

    private void flingCardAway(){
        mCurrentAnimCardContainer = findViewById(R.id.card_container);
        ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(mCurrentAnimCardContainer, 1.0f);

        AnimationSet anim = new AnimationSet(true);

        RotateAnimation rotate1 = new RotateAnimation(0,-45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f );
        rotate1.setStartOffset(100);
        rotate1.setDuration(500);
        anim.addAnimation(rotate1);

        TranslateAnimation trans1 =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        trans1.setDuration(600);
        anim.addAnimation(trans1);

        AlphaAnimation opacity1 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        opacity1.setDuration(400);
        opacity1.setStartOffset(200);
        anim.addAnimation(opacity1);

        mCurrentAnimCardContainer.setAnimation(anim);
        mCurrentAnimCardContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final FrameLayout cardFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_frame);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
//The problem area, also this is not always called
//                ((ViewGroup)mCurrentAnimCardContainer.getParent()).removeView(mCurrentAnimCardContainer);
//                  cardFrame.removeAllViews();
            }
        });
    }

    private void resetForNewCard(){
        mFlipCardLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCardFlippedButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void makeNewCard(){
        Integer childCount = mCardFrame.getChildCount();
        Log.d("Simple","childCount: "+childCount);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.study_card, mCardFrame);
    }

}
```

Is it just me or does making an Android app feel like you're constantly swimming against the current in a river.

Edit: If you want to see real improvement, explain why you think this is a bad question rather than just down voting.

Comment: try changing `setAnimation` -> `startAnimation` and see what happens

Comment: @pskink unfortunately not, it seems that setAnimation and startAnimation have the same outcome. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out onAnimationEnd and just put the removeAllView method outside of it and it worked. Honestly I have no idea how this works. One would imagine that if you remove a View it cannot have an animation work on it.

```
private void flingCardAway(){
    View currentAnimCardContainer = findViewById(R.id.card_container);
    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(currentAnimCardContainer, 1.0f);

    AnimationSet anim = new AnimationSet(true);

    RotateAnimation rotate1 = new RotateAnimation(0,-45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f );
    rotate1.setStartOffset(1);
    rotate1.setDuration(400);
    anim.addAnimation(rotate1);

    TranslateAnimation trans1 =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.5f);
    trans1.setStartOffset(1);
    trans1.setDuration(550);
    anim.addAnimation(trans1);

    AlphaAnimation opacity1 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    opacity1.setStartOffset(300);
    opacity1.setDuration(600);
    anim.addAnimation(opacity1);

    currentAnimCardContainer.startAnimation(anim);

    mCardFrame.removeAllViews();

}
```